# Can someone tell me the species of this lizard?

Tags: species, species-identification, classification

It's a green lizard with a silver tail, and it has pretty, bluish eyes. I saw it today, July 26th, trying to get some shade on a hot, sunny day (32 degrees) at around 18:00 in Austin, TX USA. It's been hot and dry here the past few weeks, but it rained a lot a few months back.

Austin has a humid subtropical climate. The city is characterized by hot summers and mild winter days and usually cool to cold winter nights. The geo coordinates are 30.4 (lat), -97.7 (long).

Oh, it was able to jump a good meter.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know nothing about lizards, but this looks like a [Carolina anole (*Anolis carolinensis*), also known as a green anole](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_anole). Apparently they can change colour:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes , an anole. Very common , more than you see because they prefer to be in trees. Sometime wrongly called chameleons.